# identify FitNesse test run with its Thread ID

Tags: java, fitnesse

I read that fitnesse is creating a new java process for each test run. I wrote the following code in Fixture class to print thread Id.

```
Thread.currentThread().getId()
```

When Run multiple tests in parallel I am getting the Thread ID as 1 for all the tests.

Does anyone have an idea, why I am getting the same ID?

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: I have posted the code. That is all I have in the Fixture class method.
Do you want me to post the FitNesse Wiki as well?

Comment: The executor thread may get the same ID in different processes if each test runs as a separate process. You should get and display the process ID with the thread ID to prove this.

Comment: @Konrad Post your comment as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executor thread may get the same ID in different processes if each test runs as a separate process. You should get and display the process ID with the thread ID to prove this.